# HTML Extend layout not working

Tags: css, html, extend

i`m using layout page called home.blade.php .here is the code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Training Management</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Free Bootstrap Theme by BootstrapMade.com">
    <meta name="keywords" content="free website templates, free bootstrap themes, free template, free bootstrap, free website template">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Raleway:300,400,900,700italic,700,300,600">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.bxslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    {!! Charts::assets() !!}

  </head>
<body>

<div class="loader"></div>
    <div id="myDiv">
    <!--HEADER-->
    <div class="header">
      <div class="bg-color">
      <header id="main-header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="home#">MOB<span class="logo-dec">ITEL</span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li class=""><a href="#feature">Trainee Details</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#service">User Registration</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#portfolio">Downloads</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#testimonial">Certificate & Evaluation</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#blog">Training Programs</a></li>
                <li class=""><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>


                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
          </ul>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        </header>


        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="banner-info text-center wow fadeIn delay-05s">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>


 @yield('content') 

    </div>


     <footer id="footer" >
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <p>&copy; All Rights Reserved.</p>
          <div class="credits">

        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
</div>


</div>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="contactform/contactform.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This layout need to use in a web page and it has extend by me but not working.here is the code.

```
`@extends('layouts.home')

@section('content')

 <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
             <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
             <table class="table table-bordered">

              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Training ID</td>
                  <td>{{ $item['trainee_id'] }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Name With Initials</td>
                  <td>{{ $item['trainee_name'] }}</td>
                  </tr>

                     <tr>
                    <td>Download Details</td>
                  <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="BankExport/{{ $item->trainee_id }}">See Here</a></td>
                  </tr>

              </tbody>
             </table> 
             </div>
             </div>
             </div>
 @endsection`
```

This the screenshot what um getting.[image]

This is the type of design um expexting
[image]

Comment: Are all of your CSS pages in the right subdirectories? (`css/bootstrap.min.css`)

Comment: Yes ,some pages work fine but pages which using this type of forms not working as i want

Comment: In Chrome, go to View > Developer > JavaScript Console, then refresh your page 127.0.0.1:8000/Bankdetails/MOB/TR/1743. Are there any errors logged?

Comment: this problem comes if 127.0.0.1:8000/Bankdetails/MOB/TR/1743.  or 127.0.0.1:8000/Bankdetails/create ,if it is like 127.0.0.1:8000/Bankdetails template works

Comment: And there aren't any errors?

Comment: No any errors but only just html no any CSS or Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put all the css and js under the public directory and then

change all the js and css call like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ public_path('css/jquery.bxslider.css') }}">
```

Comment: bro problem not fixed,problem is like this this problem comes if 127.0.0.1:8000/Bankdetails/MOB/TR/1743. or 127.0.0.1:8000/Bankdetails/create ,if it is like 127.0.0.1:8000/Bankdetails template works

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your "extends" link is not correct, based on what the question says. You say that "i'm using layout page called home.blade.php," yet in your code you extend a page called "layouts.home" (`@extends('layouts.home')`)!

You might need to make sure you are actually calling `@extends('home.blade.php')`.

If this doesn't work, and since there aren't any errors on other pages, can we see the framework for those pages to compare with this one?

Hope this helps!

Comment: if you able to come via a chat?